# Get unique value using Sharepoint CAML Query JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, caml-query, caml

I've this code below:

```
function ReceivePages(FirstFolderProd, FirstFolderWithoutSpaceProd, GetTagFolder){
        var restUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site/Negocio/OfertaParticulares/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('2 - Produtos - Páginas')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1=" + "{\"ViewXml\":\"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Computed'>Produto</Value></Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Intranet_SubCategoria' /><Value Type='TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti'>"+GetTagFolder+"</Value></Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='OfertaEmComercializa_x00e7__x00e3_o' /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' /><Value Type='ModStat'>0</Value></Eq></And></And></And></Where></Query></View>\"}";

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: restUrl,
                async: false,
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var dataresult = data.d.results;
                    dataresult = [].slice.call(dataresult);
                    dataresult.forEach(function (key, value) {
                        var SubTabs = (key.SubFamiliaParticulares.results["0"].Label);
                        var SubTabsWithoutSpace = SubTabs.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '');
                    });
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
    }
```

My List Page:
[image]

**Grupo de Produtos** is a taxonomy field (internal name *SubFamiliaParticulares*), how can I retrive unique values from that column? I already tried using **GroupBy** but didn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, [CAML query schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema) can't provide a way to get the unique values.

As a workaround, we can use JavaScript to get unique values from an array object.

The example code below for your reference.

```
var data = [{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}];

var uniqueNames = [];
for(i = 0; i< data.length; i++){    
    if(uniqueNames.indexOf(data[i].website) === -1){
        uniqueNames.push(data[i].website);        
    }        
}

for(i = 0; i< uniqueNames.length; i++){    
    alert(uniqueNames[i]);      
}
```

Refer to: [JavaScript Array Distinct()](https://codeburst.io/javascript-array-distinct-5edc93501dc4)